# How to send an "already read" message to Gmail?

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, protocols

I noticed that sometimes new messages come into my Gmail box as already "read". That is a rare event, but it happens only with the messages from banks or other financial organizations. From the perspective of a protocol like SMTP that sounds impossible to send an "already read message".

I'm curious which protocol is used in this case and how it may be possible for anyone who does not have access to Google servers to send a message to a Gmail account in such a way that the recipient would receive it read. Is that something on the bank's side, or is that a Google "feature"?

This question is not practical, it is my curiosity about how the things may work this way.

Comment: It seems somebody marks messages as read on the server.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev it could be, but who and why?